React router not rendering component on navigate()
I'm trying to navigate('/') after successful sign in, however it is not working completely. On successful sign in, I can see the url update but the <Home />(navigatable manually) component does not render and the <SignUp /> doesn't unmount. The only change that happens is in the url and nav bar, url changes from /get-started/signup to / and the Sign In button on the nav bar gets replaced by the user avatar.
The entire flow
Below is my handleSignIn function which is calling handleAuth exported from the useAuth hook.
  const { isAuthenticating, error, handleAuth } = useAuth()

  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const success = await handleAuth(signin, emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
    if (success) {
      navigate('/')
    }
  }

This hook then dispatches a thunk
From useAuth.js:
  const { isAuthenticating, error } = useSelector(state => state.user)

  const handleAuth = async (authType, email, password) => {
    try {
      const action = await dispatch(authType({ email, password }))
      if (authType.fulfilled.match(action)) {
        console.log('worked')
        return true;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return false;
    }
  }

The signin thunk:
export const signin = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/signin',
  async({ email, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      const accessToken = await response.user.getIdToken()

      return {
        uid: response.user.uid,
        email: response.user.email,
        accessToken
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message)
    }
  }
)

I'm then using extraReducers in user-slice.js to handle loading and error states and update the redux store. This(isAuthenticating, error) is what's pulled from the useAuth hook.
  const initialState = {
    user: null,
    error: {
      type: null,
      message: null
    },
    isAuthenticating: false,
  }

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signin.pending, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticating = true;
        state.error = initialState.error;
      })
      .addCase(signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.isAuthenticating = false;
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', action.payload.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('email', action.payload.email);
        localStorage.setItem('uid', action.payload.uid);
      })
      .addCase(signin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticating = false;
        state.error = handleError(action.payload);
      });
  },

Below is my router path configuration and PrivateRoute component.
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <RootLayout />,
      errorElement: <Error />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <PrivateRoute element={<Home />} />,
        },
        {
          path: 'get-started',
          element: <LandingLayout />,
          children: [
            {
              index: true,
              element: <GetStarted />,
            },
            {
              path: 'signup',
              element: <SignUp />
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

  const PrivateRoute = ({ element }) => {
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

    return user ? element : <Navigate to="/get-started" />
  }

The RootLayout
const RootLayout = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}

I'm not able to find out what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is user still falsey in PrivateRoute and you get redirected to "/get-started"? Or is the URL path still "/" and you see nothing but a blank page? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]? The root RootLayout component, and more complete Redux code so we can see how the store is configured and what that authType action is that handleAuth is using, and anything else you think might be related to your app's authentication flow?

@DrewReese - No it's not falsey, it is redirected to "/". I will update the code to add the thunk which is actually using Firebase for authentication.

When user is falsey it redirects to "/get-started", otherwise your element would be rendered. My question was basically this, after authenticating and navigating to "/" what is PrivateRoute doing? It can do only 1 of 2 things, either render the specified element or redirect to the "get started" page. Maybe Home is actually rendered but there is some error on that page/component to look for.

@DrewReese - It is trying to render the Home page which is the element as I can see the url update to root but it is not rendered.

Ok, so back to my initial question. The URL path is "/"... what is actually being rendered? Obviously the root RootLayout layout route component will be rendered. Do you see that PrivateRoute on the index route is rendered? If so, what is PrivateRoute rendering? Since you say that the app is not navigating to "/get-started" I can only assume (1) that PrivateRoute isn't rendered or (2) it is and so Home is rendered and there is some issue in Home. You need to do a bit more digging and provide us a complete [mcve] and more debugging details.

@DrewReese - I just checked, it turns out the PrivateRoute is not rendering either. Not sure what this means. I'll try to create a minimal example.

Can you [edit] to include the RootLayout component? I suspect it's missing rendering an Outlet for the nested Route components. Does this answer help?

@DrewReese - It has the Outlet. The redirect was working fine before but after working on other sections when I came back and checked something broke and the redirect stopped working.

Very odd. You get redirected to "/" and RootLayout renders, but not PrivateRoute on the nested "/" index route? Yes, some debugging details are necessary for sure. Are there any errors in the console as far as you can tell?

@DrewReese No errors what so ever. Creating a minimal demo, be back soon.

See if you can create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we can inspect live. Try to mock the response and accessToken values in your signin action so the code runs and gets to the redirection/route rendering part.

@DrewReese - So strange, it redirects fine on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hardcore-julien-rxq6t4

Issue
It looks like an issue is that Private route looks at the entire state.user object instead of just the state.user.user value that is either null or the Firebase user object.
store.js:
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer, // <-- state.user
  },
});

user-slice.js:
const initialState = {
  user: null, // <-- store.user.user
  error: {
    type: null,
    message: null,
  },
  isAuthenticating: false,
};

PrivateRoute.js
const PrivateRoute = ({ element }) => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  console.log(user); // <-- only state.user, e.g. { user , error, isAuthenticating }

  return user ? element : <Navigate to="/get-started" />;
};

In PrivateRoute user is always a defined object, so the element, or Home component will always be rendered.
Solution Suggestion
Update PrivateRoute to reference the nested state.user.user property to know if there is any current authenticated user.
const PrivateRoute = ({ element }) => {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return user ? element : <Navigate to="/get-started" />;
};

I'd suggest also integrating the isAuthenticating state to display a loading indicator while any authentication checks are in-progress.
const PrivateRoute = ({ element }) => {
  const { isAuthenticating, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (isAuthenticating) {
    return <LoadingSpinner />;
  }

  return user ? element : <Navigate to="/get-started" />;
};

Additional Suggestion
It's generally advisable for the PrivateRoute component to be implemented as a layout route component so it is capable of protecting entire groups of routes instead of one-at-a-time.
const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const { isAuthenticating, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  if (isAuthenticating) {
    return <LoadingSpinner />;
  }

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/get-started" />;
};

App.js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <PrivateRoute />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Home /> },
          // other protected routes
        ],
      }
      {
        path: "get-started",
        element: <AuthLayout />,
        children: [
          { path: "signup", element: <SignUp /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);


@ZainabHussain Hmm, does your actual app code have any other logic elsewhere that possibly handles navigations/redirections/what is rendered per URL path? I don't see any other overt issue in the posted code or linked sandbox that would cause PrivateRoute or Home not to be rendered on URL path "/". Are you deploying this app code somewhere or running it locally and serving from "localhost:xxxx/"?

No it doesn't. I'm running the code locally and yes serving from localhost.

@ZainabHussain Ok, wow, that's a tough one since I don't see any additional overt issues to comment on and it's not reproducing the same way in the sandbox. Without sitting next to you to pair/mob-program I don't think there's much else we can do with the current information.

I decided to switch to working on my other slices and revisit this later. Surprisingly, the issue is now resolved. I’m not sure what fixed it, but I hope to figure it out. Thanks so much for your help!
